# How to track iteration progress using Rally's Web Services API

Tags: node.js, rally

I am writing a custom app to track iteration progress by day. Is there a builtin way in Rally to get the number of user stories that are in the "Accepted" state for a specific date, and the number of points (or do I have to get all user stories and parse their revision histories)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is IterationCumulativeFlowData object in WS API, which is populated at midnight of the Workspace Timezone when the Data Collection runs on workdays specified in the Workspace Setup screen.

Data is stored for each day of the Iteration and a corresponding state.  There is CumulativeFlowData object for Day 1 of the Iteration for everything in a Defined state, Day 1 of Release for everything in an In-Progress state, etc.
The CumulativeFlowData object also stores CardEstimateTotal which is the sum of the estimates of cards in every state.

Here is a example of an app written with [rally-node](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node) that returns iteration data for specific state (Accepted) as of the last day of the iteration.

In this examle the CreationDate of the last result is '2013-08-27T06:00:00.000Z, while the EndDate of the iteration in question was 2013-08-27 11:59:59 PM America/Denver (which is 2013-08-28T05:59:59.000Z), so I had to manipulate a date in order to make this query condition return the data for the last day of the iteration:

```
query = query.and('CreationDate', '>', endDateMinusOneDay);
```

Here is the full js file of the example:

```
var rally = require('rally'),
    queryUtils = rally.util.query,
    restApi = rally({
        user: 'user@co.com', 
        pass: 'secret', 
        apiVersion: 'v2.0', 
        server: 'https://rally1.rallydev.com',  
        requestOptions: {
            headers: {
                'X-RallyIntegrationName': 'My cool node.js program',  
                'X-RallyIntegrationVendor': 'My company',             
                'X-RallyIntegrationVersion': '1.0'                    
            },
        }
    });

 function findIteration() {
    return restApi.query({
        type: 'Iteration',
        start: 1,
        pageSize: 2,
        limit: 10,
        fetch: ['ObjectID', 'EndDate'],
        scope: {
            project: '/project/12352608219', 
            up: false, 
            down: false 
    },
        query: queryUtils.where('Name', '=', 'i777') 
    });
}


function queryIterationData(result) {
    var endDate = result.Results[0].EndDate,
        oid = result.Results[0].ObjectID;

    console.log('endDate',endDate);

    var date1 = new Date(endDate);
    var ms = date1.getTime() - 86400000; //86400000 is the number of milliseconds in a day
    var date2 = new Date(ms);
    var endDateMinusOneDay = date2.toISOString();
    console.log('date2 ISO', date2.toISOString());

    var query = queryUtils.where('IterationObjectID', '=',oid );
    query = query.and('CardState', '=', 'Accepted');
    query = query.and('CreationDate', '>', endDateMinusOneDay);


    return restApi.query({
        type: 'IterationCumulativeFlowData',
        fetch: ['CardCount', 'CardEstimateTotal', 'CardState', 'CardState', 'CreationDate'], 
        query: query,
    });
}

function onSuccess(result) {
    console.log('Success!', result);
}

function onError(errors) {
    console.log('Failure!', errors);
}

findIteration()
    .then(queryIterationData)
    .then(onSuccess)
    .fail(onError);
```

It returns:

[image]